# Problem with Windows 10 theme on Ubuntu

Tags: windows, themes, gnome-shell

I installed a Windows 10 theme in my Ubuntu, and I don't know why there's a menu in front of the real menu, it's weird and I would like to fix it but I don't know how.

This is how it looks:

[image]

and should be like this:

[image]

How I installed windows 10 theme:

I installed windows 10 theme dark-matter, I installed gnome-tweaker, and moved the folder to ./themes, here's a screenshot of tweaker

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPid0.jpg

Comment: It seems you have some kind of extensions that are interfering. Which extensions do you have currently on the system

Comment: It looks like your Windows theme is creating the "extra" bottom panel that normally shows in real Windows. Select another theme and the problem will probably go away. You can also check that no additional GNOME extensions got installed that create that extra bottom panel. Check at https://extensions.gnome.org/local/. You must have an extension that moves the normal Ubuntu top panel to the bottom.

Comment: this are my extensions imgur.com/a/nQVYpCx imgur.com/a/svw3VA6 I disabled window list extension and window navigator.

Comment: Please don't add "SOLVED" to the title or add solution to the question itself. Since Ask Ubuntu is not like other forums, the right way to to indicate you've found a working solution is by "accepting" an answer which you've found most useful (which you already did). You can even post an answer yourself and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a list of open windows triggered by the [**Window List**](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/602/window-list/) extension (or something similar).

Run the following command in Terminal

```
gnome-shell-extension-prefs
```

A window should appear which should let you manage installed extensions. Disable the Window List extension (or the similar one).

Comment: Hi, I disabled window list extension and window navigator, I tried disabling and enabling all my extensions but the list of open windows still there https://imgur.com/a/nQVYpCx https://imgur.com/a/svw3VA6

Comment: @NoelJimenezBenages In your second screenshot, 'Window List' still looks enabled. Also you may have to relogin (or restart GNOME shell: press <Alt>+<F2>, then type `r`, finally press <Enter>) to see effect of the change made.

Comment: I restarted and the window list still here https://imgur.com/a/p0GI0Fb

Comment: @NoelJimenezBenages So you still see the window list at the bottom even after disabling the 'Window List' extension? In that case please edit your question and mention in details how you installed the "*Windows 10 theme*". Also add the outputs of the following commands in Terminal: `gsettings get org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions` and `ls /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/` and `ls ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/`.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/NA4MlrC I will edit my question and mention in detail how i installed the windows 10 theme